# How to select an element inside div->ul->li in Selenium

Tags: java, html, css, eclipse, selenium

I have a menu which displays a list on mouse hover, I want to click on Logout.
I've written some code but unable to get the desired result.

Here's my Java code:

```
public void Logout() throws Exception {
      WebElement profileDropdown = driver.findElement(By.className("profile-dropdown"));
      //profileDropdown.click();
      //profileDropdown.findElement(By.id("lnkLogout")).click();
      //Select oSelect = new Select(driver.findElement(By.className("profile-dropdown")));

         //oSelect.selectByVisibleText("Log Out");
      //List<WebElement> li = profileDropdown.findElements(By.id("lnkLogout"));
      //li.get(0).click();//If there are only two such element, here 1 is index of 2nd element in list returned.

      List<WebElement> elems = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul>li>a"));
      elems.get(5).click();
      //profileDropdown.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Log Out')])[2]")).click();

  }
```

I've tried many things, you can see the lines of code that are commented. Nothing works for me.

Here's my HTML Code, of which I'm performing automation for

```
<div style="display: none;" class="profile-dropdown">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="https://consumers.keenu.pk/index.php/profile/">My Profile <!--<label id="lblProfilePercentage">0</label>--></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://consumers.keenu.pk/index.php/transactionhist/">Transaction History</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://consumers.keenu.pk/index.php/customer-care/helpline">Helpline</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://consumers.keenu.pk/index.php/pin-pass/">PIN &amp; Password</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://consumers.keenu.pk/index.php/settings/">Favorites</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="lnkLogout" style="cursor:pointer">Log Out</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

It is able to find the "profile-dropdown" element but then throws the exception and unable to find the list element.

Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you saying that your menu items appears when you do mousehoever on menu then clicking on it is not going to work. you need to:

1.mouse hover even on menu first

2.need wait until logout menu item (link) is visible

3.click on it.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(profileDropdown).build().perform();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement logoutLink = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("lnkLogout")));
logoutLink.click();
```

Comment: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: (//a[contains(text(),'Log Out')])[2] (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)

Comment: can you try with id, i have updated the answer, also don't close the browser and check the behaviour, are you able to see menu items ?

Comment: so may be that's not the element which reacts to mouse hover event, you need to figure out which element is bind with mouse however event and need to do mouse hoever on it.

Comment: Yes, and that just made me figure it out ! Found the element, working as expected now. Thank You.